# Populating an array row with unique values recursively - Sudoku Solver

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to create a sudoku solver using the Naive/Brute Force approach. I'm starting with solving the row then moving to solving the columns with the rows followed by each sub grid.

What I'm having trouble with is exiting my recursion once I have found the unique value needed for the row. Once I have found the value I need, when the function traverses back up the recursion, it takes the top recursive value instead of the value at the bottom of the recursion giving the incorrect value returned.

For example, if my row is this:

[0,5,4,0,0,3,0,0,8]

My function will populate as follows:

[1,5,4,0,0,3,0,0,8]

[1,5,4,2,0,3,0,0,8]

[1,5,4,2,2,3,0,0,8]

But as you see, the third iteration populates the value 2 twice, when it should be a 6. When I run in debug, I see that, before my function starts to traverse back up the recursion, it populates with a 6 but then the value is changed back to a 2 when the function finally exits.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Also, feel free to give me any tips or pointers on what I already have.

Here's my code:

```
def checkExists(board, row1, col1, value):
    if value in board[row1]:
        value = value + 1
        checkExists(board, row1, col1, value)
    board[row1][col1] = value


def solveSudoku(board):
    for row in range (0,9):
        print('Beginning Row: ', board[row])
        for col in range(0,9):
            if board[row][col] == 0:
                value = 1
                checkExists(board, row, col, value)
                print('New Row:       ', board[row])
                time.sleep(2)
```

EDIT:

Thanks to Ajay below for seeing my silly mistake. I needed the else statement in my recursive function.

Comment: `def checkExists(board, row1, col1, value):`. The function takes 4 parameters but you're passing 5 in `checkExists(board, row1, col1, value, count)`. If that's a typing mistake, please correct it.

Comment: I have fixed this issue. It should not have had the 5th parameter. I was attempting to count the recursions for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're missing the else block in `checkExists`. If `value` is in current row, you increment value by 1 and recurse again but without the `else` block, 2 will be set as the value in row when you trace back in recursion.

```py
def checkExists(board, row1, col1, value):
    if value in board[row1]:
        value = value + 1
        checkExists(board, row1, col1, value)
    else: # <<-- missing else
        board[row1][col1] = value
```

Comment: This worked correctly. I thought I had tried that, but I guess I did something wrong. Thanks so much, i've been racking my brain for an hour on this.